# remove spaces from beginning of lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i have a vb.net project and
i have text in a multi-line textbox
like this

```
  abc
  def
   ghi
        jkl
 mn
```

every line starts with spaces
i want to remove the initial spaces from all line

i've tried

```
For Each lne In TextBox1.Lines
            If lne.StartsWith(" ") Then
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "")
            End If
        Next
```

but it deletes other texts in the text box and won't work

Comment: You need to use a regular expression somehow. In POSIX regex notation, you want to replace `^[[:space:]]*` with the empty string. I don't know how to do that in vb.net.

Comment: RegEx?  For this?  Overkill, overkill, overkill.

Comment: Overkill^Overkill, infact.

Comment: I agree with the general usage of `TrimStart`, but it is important to note that your code is basically saying "As soon as I find a line with a leading space, delete ALL spaces in my textbox". That is why it will be modifying more than you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Dim result As String = ""
For Each lne In TextBox1.Lines
   result += lne.TrimStart() & Environment.NewLine
Next
TextBox1.Text = result
```

The above method uses the [`String.TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) function to remove the leading whitespaces from each line.

Comment: Note that TextBox1's Text field is only overwritten at the end. That is an important difference to the original problem code. The only thing I would change is using a `StringBuilder` instead of String Concatenation