# Remove initial space from lines, keeping others spaces in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove the initial space from lines, like show below:

From

(space)09/Mar/21     16,997,520.6

To

09/Mar/21     16,997,520.6

I've tryed this : [remove spaces from beginning of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955197/remove-spaces-from-beginning-of-lines) , but removed all spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove leading whitespace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959215/how-do-i-remove-leading-whitespace-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question that you have a `file` loaded, with multiple lines (where  `09/Mar/21 16,997,520.6` is one of those lines). Have you tried something like:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    <--- Do stuff with the line --->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .lstrip(' ')

```
string = '    09/Mar/21 16,997,520.6'

print(string.lstrip(' '))

>>> 09/Mar/21 16,997,520.6
```

.lstrip() method will remove whatever is passed into it at the beginning of string.

For example:

```
print(string.lstrip(' 09'))
>>> /Mar/21 16,997,520.6
```

Answer (score 0):

python

```
" 09/Mar/21 16,997,520.6".lstrip()
```

or pandas specific

```
df = pd.DataFrame([" 09/Mar/21 16,997,520.6"], columns = ['dummy_column'])
df['dummy_column'].str.lstrip()
```